# Why does "cherry-or-revert" appear in my powerlevel9k prompt?

Tags: themes, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Trying out Powerlevel9k for my iTerm font. Seems to be working but in one particular project it adds `cherry-or-revert` after the branch name.

[image]

The branch `master` in the 'problem' repo is clean and there is nothing staged or in the working directory.

This doesn't happen in other repos like `~/.oh-my-zsh`, for example, or even other Rails projects.

What am I missing?

Comment: https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k/issues/224

Comment: @SushiHangover - make that an answer and I'll accept. `git cherry-pick --quit` solved it for me.

Comment: In my case, I use `git revert --quit`

Answer (score 12):

You may have been in the process of a git cherry pick in this particular repo when you ran into this. I've seen this after cherry picking and having merge conflicts. After reseting or resolving there is still a state that is left to indicate the cherry pick sequence. The `cherry-or-revert` message is then displayed. This can be fixed by exiting cherry pick by running:

```
git cherry-pick --quit
```